# How do I open the first cell in Modern Collection Views programmatically?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

Playing around with [Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views), I managed to create a custom UIContentView. Great. Now I would like to open the first cell/row programmatically. How do I go about doing that? This is what I would like to see on startup. [image]

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Lee Kah Seng](https://github.com/LeeKahSeng/SwiftSenpai-UICollectionView-List) for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up with:

```
    addItems(menuItems, to: nil)

    // expand first section
    snapshot.expand([menuItems[0]])

    return snapshot
```